# Mongodb Aggregation orderless items in Group _id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am storing messages between users in a collection with this schema:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23c455e3fce278f9e8d05f"), //message id
        "f" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"), //sender userid
        "c" : "Hi", //contents
        "t" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4"), //reciever userid
}
```

I am trying to query db to generate a list of current user conversations just like whatsapp list with the last message embedded using this aggregation:

```
    db.getCollection('message').aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $or: [ { f: ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca") }, {t:ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca")} ] } },
      {
        $group : {
           _id :{f:"$f",t:"$t"},
          c: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Result is:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "f" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"),
        "t" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4")
    },
    "c" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b23c455e3fce278f9e8d05f"),
            "f" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"),
            "c" : "Hi",
            "t" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4"),
            "d" : ISODate("2018-06-15T13:48:34.000Z"),
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "f" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4"),
        "t" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca")
    },
    "c" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b235fea43966a767d2d9604"),
            "f" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4"),
            "c" : "Hello",
            "t" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"),
            "d" : ISODate("2018-06-15T06:40:07.000Z"),
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there is a conversation between 5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca and 5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4. The group acts on f and t with their order. But we do just need to find conversations regardless of the order of f and t. Thus, the result document should be just like this with the latest message embedded:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "x" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"),
        "y" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4")
    },
    "c" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b23c455e3fce278f9e8d05f"),
            "f" : ObjectId("5ad13aaa1ba073601cc16bca"),
            "c" : "Hi",
            "t" : ObjectId("5ad2de5c691a4008cf6923b4"),
            "d" : ISODate("2018-06-15T13:48:34.000Z"),
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I handle this with aggregation? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can handle it with an aggregation! As your `_id`s are `ObjectId`s, you can compare them with relational operators, therefore you can use [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) and [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) on them:

```
db.getCollection('message').aggregate([
    {$match: {$or: [{f: _id}, {t: _id}]}},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            x: {$max: ['$f', '$t']},
            y: {$min: ['$f', '$t']}
        },
        c: {$push: '$$ROOT'}}
    }
])
```

Comment: Oh, that's perfect and what I really looking for. Thanks. You're a life saver.